# Why is my while/if statement not working?

Tags: python

Im making my own Hangman Python program, im still a newbie to python programming, so i dont quite understand what im doing wrong. I have specified that the lives are limited to 6, but when inputing a wrong input, the lives can go down to -2 as the console says..

```
import random

words = ["stone"]
word = words[random.randint(0, (len(words)) - 1)]
wordToLetters = list(word)
gaps = ["_"] * len(word)
lives = 6
gameOver = False
while not gameOver:
    for num, x in enumerate(wordToLetters):
        print(lives)
        print(gaps)
        eingabe = input("Buchstaben eingeben: ")
        if lives < 0:
            gameOver = True
            print("spiel verloren...\n")
        if gaps == wordToLetters:
            print("Spiel gewonnen!\n")
            print("Das Wort war: " + word)
            gameOver = True
        if eingabe in wordToLetters:
            if eingabe in gaps:
                lives -= 1
                print("Buchstabe schon geraten!")
            else:
                gaps[num] = eingabe
                print("Buchstabe vorhanden!\n")
        else:
            lives -= 1
            print("Buchstabe nicht vorhanden! :(\n")
```

Comment: Which if not working?

Comment: "if lives < 0:" the lives counter goes down to -2, even though it should only be able to go down to 0 maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use elif to not test the other conditions when one of them is true:

```
import random

words = ["stone"]
word = words[random.randint(0, (len(words)) - 1)]
wordToLetters = list(word)
gaps = ["_"] * len(word)
lives = 6
gameOver = False
while not gameOver:
    for num, x in enumerate(wordToLetters):
        print(lives)
        print(gaps)
        eingabe = input("Buchstaben eingeben: ")
        if lives < 0:
            gameOver = True
            print("spiel verloren...\n")
        elif gaps == wordToLetters:
            print("Spiel gewonnen!\n")
            print("Das Wort war: " + word)
            gameOver = True
        elif eingabe in wordToLetters:
            if eingabe in gaps:
                lives -= 1
                print("Buchstabe schon geraten!")
            else:
                gaps[num] = eingabe
                print("Buchstabe vorhanden!\n")
        else:
            lives -= 1
            print("Buchstabe nicht vorhanden! :(\n")
```

here if the first "if" is true then we will not check the others.